# Lazy quantifier for an exact word in large text with newlines

Tags: regex, latex

I am trying to find the correct regex to extract the filenames associated with a given label inside a figure environment in a large file. This is my test case

```
\begin{figure}[t]

  \caption{caption text}\label{labeltext}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{figurename.pdf}

  more text

\end{figure}

lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
        
\begin{figure}[t]

  \caption{caption text}\label{labeltext2}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{figurename2.pdf}

  more text
\end{figure}
```

from which I want to extract something like

```
labeltext  figurename.pdf
labeltext2 figurename2.pdf
```

I am willing to use any solution, such as grep, etc..

When I try the following (using javascript regex), the regex matches all text
`\\begin{figure}.*$(\n.*)*(\\includegraphics)?`
if I try, instead
`\\begin{figure}.*$(\n.*)*(\\includegraphics)`
the regex does the right thing by matching greedily until the second includegraphics. How do I make \includegraphics lazy?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context what you are trying to do with the label and filename?

Comment: I thought I described it. I want to extract a list of labels with the corresponding filenames, 
labeltext  figurename.pdf

labeltext2 figurename2.pdf

Comment: And what do you want to do with this list?

Comment: The readme file I have to write requires me to write a table that matches figure numbers in the article with the line of the code where it is generated. I can do this part (figure numbers are pulled from the latex aux file using the label, and using the figure filename I can find the code location that generates it in the .py file). Therefore, what I outline above is only the first step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups, and if supported using a negative lookahead to prevent matching lines that start with `\includegraphics`

```
\\begin{figure}.*\r?\n\s*.*\blabel{([^{}]+)}(?:\r?\n(?!\s*\\includegraphics).*)*\r?\n\s*\\includegraphics.*{([^{}]+)}
```

Then pattern matches

- `\\begin{figure}.*` Match `\begin{figure}` and the rest of the line
- `\r?\n\s*` Match a newline and optional whitespace chars
- `.*\blabel` Match the whole line and then `label`
- `{([^{}]+)}` Backtrack to the last `{` and capture any char other than `{` or `}` in **group 1** followed by matching `}`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!\s*\\includegraphics).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with `\includegraphics`
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat it
- `\r?\n\s*\\includegraphics.*` Match a newline, optional whitespace chars and then match `\includegraphics` and the rest of the line
- `{([^{}]+)}` Backtrack until `{` and capture any char other than `{` and `}` in **group 2** followed by matching `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ekMWhB/1)

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask someone who already has all the information you want?

Latex can write this information to a file for you, including the line number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile=\jobname.foo
\def\figurestring{figure}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\label}{%
  \@ifundefined{@captype}{}{%
  \ifx\@captype\figurestring%
    \immediate\write\myfile{#1}%
  \fi%
  }%
}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\Gin@ii}{%
  \@ifundefined{@captype}{}{%
  \ifx\@captype\figurestring%
    \immediate\write\myfile{l.\the\inputlineno\space\thefigure\space #2}%
  \fi%
  }%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\label{foo}

\begin{figure}[t]

  \caption{caption text}\label{labeltext}
  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image}

  more text

\end{figure}

lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
        
\begin{figure}[t]

  \caption{caption text}\label{labeltext2}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{example-image-duck}

  more text
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```